# $\pi$ and $e$ as irrational linear combinations

Tags: number-theory

Let $S=\{m\cdot n^r\mid m,n\in\mathbb Z,r\in\mathbb Q\}$
Can $e$ or $\pi$ be written as a finite sum of elements of $S$?

Can $\pi=xe$, with $x$ algebraic?

Comment: Since the members of $S$ are algebraic, while $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental...

Comment: Also noting that a finite sum of algebraics is algebraic...

Comment: For the new question: it is not yet known if $\pi/e$ is algebraic or transcendental.

Comment: See also [this thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As finite sums, no. If you could, you'll get that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraic numbers, which is known to be false.

As infinite sums:

$$e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n!}$$

$$\pi = 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$